# Java - If I return in a catch block, will the finally block be executed?

Tags: java, scope, try-catch-finally

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
try {

    //code
} catch (Exception e) {

    return false;
} finally {

    //close resources
}
```

Will this work? Is it bad practice? Would it be better doing this:

```
boolean inserted = true;

try {

    //code
} catch (Exception e) {

    inserted = false;
} finally {

    //close resources
}

return inserted;
```

Comment: tried yourself?

Comment: dup alert! did you try searching? this has been asked several times over...

Comment: @devnull I researched but I was not sure if it was a good thing to do. Some topics said it was OK, while other people said it wasn't very good.

Comment: and are you certain of *identical* responses now?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it will. The only things that can prevent a finally block to execute (AFAIR) are `System.exit()`, and an infinite loop (and a JVM crash, of course).

Comment: ... and a power outage :) (blast, you ruined it with adding the JVM crash)

Comment: But is my first example a bad practice?

Comment: The interesting bit, overlooked by many, is that `Thread#stop` will *not* prevent the `finally` from executing.

Comment: @Thecoolguyacrossthestreet: No, it's not. It's completely fine.

Comment: @Thecoolguyacrossthestreet I would say the first is the simplest and what I would do.

Comment: @Thecoolguyacrossthestreet It would be a bad practice, if you had a return statement also in finally block because your catch block's return statement would be useless in that case.

Comment: @SajalDutta I see... thanks. In this case I'll the first example. I'll be sure to remember not to return anything at the finally block.

Comment: @Thecoolguyacrossthestreet You got it!

Comment: Just to add, if the main thread exits, finally block of daemon threads are also not executed.

Answer (score 7):

The `finally` block is executed *always, unconditionally*, as the last thing the `try-catch-finally` block does. Even if you execute `Thread#stop` against it, the `finally` block will still execute, just as if a regular exception ocurred.

Not just that, if you return from `finally`, that return value will trample over the return from either `try` or `catch`.

BTW Your first example is not just fine, but preferred. In the second example the reader must chase around the assignments to the variable, which is a  tedious job and lets bugs slip through very easily.

Comment: im not agreed with  `..btw ` part ,i think is better to have only one return statement but that brings me to find about that here (where did the notion of one return only come from)[http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from]

Comment: That's a nice writeup! (the first answer)

Answer (score 4):

Both are approximately the same. However, be careful with the following case:

```
int i = 0;

try
{
    //code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    return i;
}
finally
{
    i = 1;
}
```

`0` is what will be returned.

Comment: Then I think my example is not a good practice, right?

Comment: @Thecoolguyacrossthestreet The best practice is to use clean code whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that it's described in [the specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2):

> If the catch block completes abruptly for reason R, then the finally block is executed.

where of course

> It can be seen, then, that a return statement always completes abruptly.